Find the ratio of the area of ​the triangle $PRQ$ ¸and the area of ​the triangle $ETA$
the problem
On the side $BC$ of the triangle $ABC$, the points $D$ and $E$ are considered such that $BD = DE = EC$. Let $M$
the middle of the segment $AD$, $BM ∩ AE = {P}, CM ∩ AE = {Q}$. $RM$ ¸and $TD$ perpendiculars are constructed
on the plane $(ABC)$, on the same side of it, so that $TD = 2RM$. The ratio of the area of ​​the triangle
$PRQ$ ¸and the area of ​​the triangle $ETA$ has the value...?
my idea
drawing

$A(ETA)= dis(T,AE)*AE/2$ and $A(PRQ)=dis*(R,PQ)*PQ/2=> \frac{A(PRQ)}{A(ETA) }= \frac{dis*(R,PQ)*PQ}{dis(T,AE)*AE}$
I think it is clear that $AD \cap AT$, because $RM$ is a midline in triangle ATD
I noted $RM=a=> TD=2a$ and $dis(M,PQ)=b=> dis(D,AE)=2b$ I calculated this by the thorem of the similarity and by applying the thorem of phytagoras we get that $dis(T,AE)= 2* \sqrt{a^2+b^2}, dis(R,PQ)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ so $\frac{A( PRQ)}{A(ETA)}= \frac{PQ}{2*AE}$
I also saw that Q is the center of gravity of the triangle ADC
I know that the answer is $\frac{1}{6}$, so basically we have to show that P is the midpoint of AQ.
Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

You should draw your figures with a ruler (I intended to say it already in your yesterday question), or even better use Geogebra.

In triangle $BCM$:
$$
{BD\over BC}={MQ\over MC}={1\over3}.
$$
Hence $DQ\parallel BM$ and in triangle $ADQ$ we have:
$$
{AM\over AD}={AP\over AQ}={1\over2}.
$$
